# TFS 2015 Web Portal On-Premises Backlogs not listing WI with custom states

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, states

I've customised a copy of the TFS 2015 default Scrum Process Template which I'm using for my Team Project. Apart from a GUID and name change in the ProcessTemplate.xml, I've only amended the "WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\ ***ProductBacklogItem.xml*** " file.

Included in the ProductBacklogItem.xml, I've added three new States and the workflow in Visual Studio 2015 and TFS WebPortal works as intended.

**PROBLEM**

In my Team Project via TFS WebPortal, WORK|Backlog main window, are a list of Product Backlog Items (WI) in various States. The Work Items passing through my customised workflow also get listed until they're in one of my customised new states - then they just disappear until brought back into a standard State.

**QUESTION**

How can I get WI's in a customised state to also be listed in Backlog? Where is it's query set?

Yes, will work by creating a query, but the business relies on this.

I've identified the "WorkItem Tracking\Process\ ***ProcessConfiguration.xml*** " file but errors when uploading via *witadmin importprocessconfig* tool on the existing *Epic* WorkItemColor element if I make changes or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the **RequirementBacklog** section of ProcessConfiguration definition for the WIT you're adding. Specifically, make sure that the following conditions are met:

> - Map the start of each workflow state to **type="Proposed"**
> - Map each intermediate workflow state you want to have show up on the    Kanban board to **type="InProgress"**
> - Map the end of each workflow state to **type="Complete"**
> - Make sure that you have only one State mapped to **type="Complete"**

For example, add the Pending workflow state:

```
  <States>
    <State value="New" type="Proposed" />
    <State value="Active" type="InProgress" />
    <State value="Pending" type="InProgress" />
    <State value="Resolved" type="InProgress" />
    <State value="Closed" type="Complete" />
  </States>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the new states in the [processconfig.xml](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/process-configuration-xml-element) file under the appropriate backlog configuration.

I will need more info on the error you receiving to know for sure, but it could be that you have not "[configured](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/backlogs/organize-backlog#team-services-or-tfs-2015-update-1)" the Epic on your backlogs, so it is not finding that work item type.

Comment: In the processconfig.xml, I can't see an obvious backlog for a ProductBacklogItem.

Comment: I have available: PortfolioBacklogs (1 x category="Microsoft.EpicCategory, 1 x category="Microsoft.FeatureCategory" parent="Microsoft.EpicCategory"), RequirementBacklog, TaskBacklog, BugWorkItems,and FeedbackRequestWorkItems.

Comment: Only the TaskBacklog columns match my WebPortal screen where I have the issue, but the existing States don't match the states in the ProductBacklogItem. Regardless, I’ve added the new States to here and others where the default States match.

Comment: But every time I upload I get the following error:
“The following element contains an error: WorkItemColor. TF401092: This element defines the color for the work item types for this team project. A 'WorkItemColor' element has the following value for the 'name' attribute: 'Epic'. A workItemColor element must refer to an existing work item type in the team project. Modify the name attribute to an existing work item type, or remove the element.”

Comment: Above error occurs even downloading a sterile Process Template from the factory default one, making no changes and upload the processconfig.xml. It always throws this error.

Comment: The product backlog refers to the "RequirementBacklog", so you need to make sure the states that you are looking to show on the backlog is referred to in that grouping.

Either remove the Epic work item color or enable it as indicated thorugh this https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/backlogs/organize-backlog#team-services-or-tfs-2015-update-1

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM FOUND AND RESOLVED

Without duplicating myself, I've posted the solution on the Microsoft forum where I was running this question in parallel. Essentially it was because of Epics being introduced in TFS2015 upgrade.

**SOLOUTION:** [Backlogs not listing Product Backlog Items with custom states in TFS 2015 Web Portal](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b097ba11-fe1c-4da8-a6e3-fbcfff27e6ec/backlogs-not-listing-product-backlog-items-with-custom-states-in-tfs-2015-web-portal?forum=tfsprocess)

*Thank you Cece for your comment as that helped me in where to put my new States.*